# My implementation of a queue in js doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: javascript, linked-list, queue

My Queue looks like this.

```
    class Queue{
    constructor(){
        this.head = this.tail = undefined   //empty
        this.length = 0
    }

    enqueue(item){
        const node = {value: item} //create a new node
        this.length++ //increase length since we are adding an element
        if (!this.tail){
            this.tail = this.head = {value: item}
        }

        this.tail.next = node //add the new node to the end of the queue 
        this.tail = node //move the tail to point to the new node last node.
    }

    deque(){  //we always deque from the head in queues
        if (!this.head){
            return undefined //if no head there is nothing to deque so undefined
        }

        this.length-- //decrease length since we are dequeuing

        const head = this.head //save current head in the variable

        this.head = this.head.next //move head to point to the next element

        head.next = undefined //remove the link to the dequeued element
        
        if (this.length === 0){
            this.tail = undefined
        }

        return head.value
    }

    peek(){
        return this.head?.value //just return the value of the head
    }


    }
```

Then I call following methods:

```
    let newQ = new Queue()

    newQ.enqueue('rawr')

    newQ.enqueue('meow')

    //queue looks like this rawr => meow because we add from the tail. 

    newQ.deque()

    //now it looks like this: meow (because rawr was first in and now it's first out)

    console.log(newQ.peek())//outputs rawr
```

Why is the output of my `console.log` "rawr" instead of "meow"???

I was expecting a meow instead of a rawr. When I implement the queue using stardard `shift()` and `push()` methods instead of linked lists, it works as expected. I need to implement this using linked lists because I want to get a better understanding of linked lists.

Comment: This piece seems odd: `this.tail = this.head = {value: item}`; what is it supposed to achieve?

Comment: @mykaf          If the queue is empty, it's supposed to add a new node and make it the tail and the head of the queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that in `enqueue`, the `if` block does not have a `return` statement. As a consequence execution continues to set `this.tail.next` to `node`, so now you have a list with two nodes instead of one, and they both have the same value: "rawr". This explains that after dequeuing one item, the output of `peek()` is still "rawr".

Secondly, there should be no need to create `{value: item}` twice.

So change this:

```
        if (!this.tail){
            this.tail = this.head = {value: item};
        }
```

to this:

```
        if (!this.tail){
            this.tail = this.head = node; // use `node`
            return; // All done!
        }
```

Not a problem, but:

- You don't need to do `head.next = undefined;` because `head` is local variable and will not be accessed after `deque` has run to completion. In fact, you could actually save the *value* in a local variable instead of the node reference.
- End statements with a semi-colon. Although the engine provides automatic semicolon insertion, it is better to not leave it to that algorithm, but take control over this yourself.
- The word `deque` has a different [meaning and pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) than `dequeue`. You want the second one.

Corrected Snippet:

```js
class Queue{
    constructor(){
        this.head = this.tail = undefined;
        this.length = 0;
    }
    
    enqueue(item){
        const node = {value: item};
        this.length++;
        if (!this.tail){
            this.tail = this.head = node;
            return;
        }
        this.tail.next = node;
        this.tail = node;
    }

    dequeue() {
        if (!this.head) {
            return undefined; 
        }
        this.length--;
        const value = this.head.value;
        this.head = this.head.next;
        if (this.length === 0) {
            this.tail = undefined;
        }
        return value;
    }

    peek() {
        return this.head?.value;
    }
}

const newQ = new Queue();
newQ.enqueue('rawr');
newQ.enqueue('meow');
newQ.dequeue();
console.log(newQ.peek());
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I will keep your suggestions in mind.

Answer (score 1):

When you make your initial tail, you are setting its `.next` to itself also. Your code `this.tail.next = node` should be in an `else` block of the above `if` block, and when you set `this.tail = this.head = {value: item}`, try setting that equal to node instead so you can set `this.head` indirectly the second time you call this method.

```
enqueue(item){
    const node = {value: item} //create a new node
    this.length++ //increase length since we are adding an element
    if (!this.tail){
        this.tail = this.head = node
    } else {
        this.tail.next = node //add the new node to the end of the queue
    }
    this.tail = node //move the tail to point to the new node last node.
}
```

Comment: @trincot's answer is better than mine. Make sure you don't accept this one.